# Apple review: section 11.14 of review guidelines to play content

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have developed an app containing medical documents. This app is going to be distributed through the app store for free.

The app can not be used by everyone, but it can be used only by doctors. For this reason I have put a form in the home screen of the app asking for a password. This password will be distributed for free by e-mail to all doctors, together with a link to Apple Store asking them to download the app.

I have submitted app for review, but it has been rejected for this reason:
"We found your app inappropriately unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
Specifically, we found that your app requires a code in order to work.
It would be more appropriate to revise or remove this feature."

After some messages sent to review team, they have confirmed that app is in compliance with section 11.14 of review guidelines

```
"11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App"
```

but not with section 11.1

```
"11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected"
```

So, my question is: how can I let user read or play reserved content without using a password or code? Please not that the content is free, it does not need to be purchased outside the app.

Comment: If the content is free, why not open it to everyone?  It seems silly to arbitrarily limit it to only certain people.  And how will you distribute the password to "all" doctors, or even verify that someone is actually a doctor?  What about nurses, paramedics, med students, etc?

Comment: The app can not be opened to everyone because of European legislation related to medical documentation. Password will be distributed during meetings and conferences.
However, I can not take the decision of removing access code, this is a decision that my client should take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i found was to change the password auth system with a standard login-password auth system that check input on a remote server.